# Perform query and field collapse

Tags: elasticsearch

When i do a multi-condition query and apply field collapsing to one of the field in the mentioned index i get following error

```
no mapping found for `search_type.keyword` in order to collapse on
```

Query Used :

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : { 
      "must" : [
        {
         "match" : 
          { 
            "id" : "123456" 
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "_index": ["history"] 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    },
    "collapse" : {
        "field" : "search_type.keyword",
         "inner_hits": {
        "name": "terms",
        "size": 10
        }
    }
}
```

Error Trace:

```
{
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "test",
        "node" : "UOA44HkATh61krg6ht3paA",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "no mapping found for `search_type.keyword` in order to collapse on"
        }
      }
```

Currently, am applying the query only for index - **history** but the result throws exception for indexes that i haven't mentioned. Please help how to narrow down field collapsing to a particular index.

Answer (score -1):

It appears to be a bug, but if you notice your result carefully, you should be able to view the response you are looking for at *the very end* after all the such errors are observed.

But then again why not add the index name to the front and modify your query as below:

```
POST history/_search                          <---- Add index name here
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "id": "123456"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse" : {
    "field" : "search_type.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "terms",
      "size": 10
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Im using this query in search template where index name will differ based on the requirement hence try to accomplish with index name inside the query.

Comment: Sorry in that case, this appears to be a bug!! Let me do some more research and let you know.